Book about village girl who falls in love with shape-shifting dragon man who disguises himself as a wealthy merchant
This book was first in a series, and the premise was that there was this small village next to a big castle that supposedly held a vicious dragon. Every set number of years, the prettiest girl in the village was supposed to be sacrificed to the dragon (to be eaten, I think was the assumption).
The main character was a girl, and she meets this wealthy young merchant in the village one market day, who says he’s the new owner of the castle, dragon rumor aside. The two fall in love, and he eventually reveals that he is the dragon when she visits a nearby lake and one of the village boys tries to assault her. As the dragon, he flies in and saves her and brings her back to the castle, where she spends the night.
Back in the village, the guy who tried to assault her convinces everyone that the dragon kidnapped her, and they become an angry crowd who wants to storm the castle. The main character intervenes somehow, and I think that leads to the happy ending.
This book is the first one in a series, and one of the other books follows the sister of this main character. Most of the dragons are male, and the lore is that they have to mate with human females to have children, but I think the last book in the series features a female dragon who manages to have an egg after mating with a male human in her human form.
The main character of the first book had a name like Katarina I think? I may be completely off the mark there, but I thought it started with a K. I would have read this book between 2013 and 2019.

Also on Reddit here
